# Why is my React delete function "deleting" the wrong object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import User from "./components/User.js"
import Project from "./components/Project.js"
import CreateForm from "./CreateForm.js";
import DeleteForm from "./DeleteForm.js";

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            projectList: [],
            myProjects: [],
            userList: [],
            currentUser: "Guest"
        };

        this.createProject = this.createProject.bind(this);
        this.deleteProject = this.deleteProject.bind(this);
        }

    createProject(title, desc, langs, len, exp) {
        this.setState({
            projectList: [...this.state.projectList, {
                title : title,
                description : desc,
                language : langs,
                length : len,
                experience : exp,
                user : this.state.currentUser
            }]
        });
    }

    deleteProject(title) {
        const projects = this.state.projectList.filter(
            p => p.title !== title 
        );
        this.setState({projectList : projects});
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <CreateForm createProject = {this.createProject} />
                <DeleteForm deleteProject = {this.deleteProject} />
                <h1> Project List: </h1>
                {this.state.projectList.map((params) =>
                <Project {...params}/>)}
            </div>
        );
    }

    
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React from "react";

class DeleteForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        title: ""
      };
  
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {

      event.preventDefault();

      this.props.deleteProject(
        this.state.title
      )
      
    }
  
    handleInputChange(event) {
      const target = event.target;
      const value = target.value;
      const name = target.name;
  
      this.setState({
        [name]: value
      });
    }
  
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
            <h2> Delete Project: </h2>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <label>
                Title:
                <input
                name="title"
                type="textbox"
                checked={this.state.title}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
            </label>
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
            </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

export default DeleteForm;
```

I have a bit of code here which attempts to "delete" created projects from my project list. It works by filtering any projects with a certain title out, and using that as the new project list. However, when I create more than one project, trying to delete the first project unrenders the second project, and then when I delete the second project after the first deletion, it unrenders the first project. Example: I create Car then Apple in that order, I delete Car, which deletes Apple, then I delete Apple, which deletes Car.

PS: I excluded some code to make things simpler.

[image: After creating Car then Apple in that order]

[image: After deleting Car]

[image: I now delete Apple after deleting Car]

Answer (score 0):

This issue happens because you haven't provided `key` prop to the JSX returned from the map function and hence when you delete an item, react isn't able to properly determine which element to remove from your DOM

Adding a unique key prop will work for you

```
 {this.state.projectList.map((params) =>
            <Project key={params.title} {...params}/>
  )}
```